# Why is this enum code an illegal reference to a static field?

Tags: java, enums

This code won't compile because there is an illegal reference to a static field.

```
public enum Foo {

  A,
  B;

  private Foo[] foos = new Foo[] { Foo.A };

}
```

Shouldn't you be able to access static fields from a non-static field initializer?  For example:

```
public class Foo {

  static int A;

  private int[] foos = new int[] { Foo.A };

}
```

This compiles fine.

Note, making `foos` static in the first example compiles.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out Java Language Specification, Third Edition, Section 8.9 at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.9

> It is a compile-time error to reference a static field of an enum type
>   that is not a compile-time constant (§15.28) from constructors,
>   instance initializer blocks, **or instance variable initializer
>   expressions of that type**. It is a compile-time error for the
>   constructors, instance initializer blocks, or instance variable
>   initializer expressions of an enum constant e to refer to itself or to
>   an enum constant of the same type that is declared to the right of e.

**Discussion**

> Without this rule, apparently reasonable code would fail at run time
>   due to the initialization circularity inherent in enum types. (A
>   circularity exists in any class with a "self-typed" static field.)
>   Here is an example of the sort of code that would fail:

```
enum Color {
        RED, GREEN, BLUE;
        static final Map<String,Color> colorMap = 
        new HashMap<String,Color>();
        Color() {
            colorMap.put(toString(), this);
        }
    }
```

> Static initialization of this enum type would throw a
>   NullPointerException because the static variable colorMap is
>   uninitialized when the constructors for the enum constants run. The
>   restriction above ensures that such code won't compile.

Answer (score 7):

Written out in a roughly equivalent, simpler way, closer to the byte code, we see:

```
public final class Foo {
    public static final Foo A = new Foo();
    public static final Foo B = new Foo();

    private Foo[] foos;

    private Foo() {
        this.foos = new Foo[] { Foo.A };
    }
}
```

You can see that to initialise `A` we are calling the constructor, which reads `A`. Obviously, whilst still in the constructor `A` will not have been initialised.

(As it turns out, this simpler code does compile. It just doesn't do what you might expect.)

You probably want `Foo.values()` instead of the `foos` instance variable.